# Select with Row_Number using join. Fetching last three customers with their respective addresses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch the last three customers from my database with their respective addresses without using `TOP` statement because using that way should be wrong. For that purpose I'm using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

This is my query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.customerId DESC) AS lastCustomers, *
    FROM Customer c JOIN Address a ON c.customerId = a.customerId
) 
WHERE lastCustomers <= 3
```

When I'm executing this query I've got the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Can anyone solve this syntax error for this query?

Comment: You probably just need a table alias after the subquery.  Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What is wrong with `TOP` (or the-like) in this situation?

Comment: I've tried but I've got another error: "'off' column specified many times for p". p should be my table alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server -- as with many other databases -- requires table aliases for subqueries:

```
SELECT ca.*
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.customerId DESC) AS lastCustomers,
             c.*, a.*   -- might get an error for repeated columns
      FROM Customer c JOIN
           Address a
           ON c.customerId = a.customerId

      ) ca
WHERE lastCustomers <= 3;
```

This will then generate an error because the subquery has repeated columns.

Generally, this is easier to write as:

```
SELECT TOP (3) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.customerId DESC) AS lastCustomers,
             c.*, a.*   -- might get an error for repeated columns
FROM Customer c JOIN
     Address a
     ON c.customerId = a.customerId
ORDER BY c.customerId DESC;
```

Comment: Have you got query recently deleted? that one specifies FETCH instruction. I need to see deleted query. I want to know if I can prove it